# Calling a shell script that is stored in another shell script variabl

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I searched SO but could not find any relevant post with this specific problem. I would like to know how to call a shell script which is stored in a variable of another shell script.
In the below script I am trying to read service name & corresponding shellscript, check if the service is running, if not, start the service using the shell script associated with that service name. tried multiple options shared in various forums(like 'eval' etc) with no luck. please help to provide your suggestions on this.

**checker.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
while read service
do
servicename=`echo $service | cut -d: -f1`
servicestartcommand=`echo $service | rev | cut -d: -f1 | rev`
    if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $servicename | wc -l) > 0 ))
    then
        echo "$servicename Running"
    else
        echo "!!$servicename!! Not Running, calling $servicestartcommand"
        eval "$servicestartcommand"
    fi
done < names.txt
```

**Names.txt**

```
WebSphere:\opt\software\WebSphere\startServer.sh
WebLogic:\opt\software\WebLogic\startWeblogic.sh
```

Comment: What do you mean by *which is stored in a variable **of another shell script**?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script can be refactored into this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=: read -r servicename servicestartcommand; do    
    if ps cax | grep -q "$servicename"; then
        echo "$servicename Running"
    else
        echo "!!$servicename!! Not Running, calling $servicestartcommand"
        $servicestartcommand
    fi
done < names.txt
```

- No need to use `wc -l` after `grep`'s output as you can use `grep -q`
- No need to use read full line and then use `cut`, `rev` etc later. You can use `IFS=:` and read the line into 2 separate variables
- No need to use `eval` in the end

Comment: If `$servicestartcommand` includes options or parameters then that will fail because you have double quotes around it.

Comment: Yes but it appears `servicestartcommand` is just the full path of some script as per the question

Comment: @anubhava Many thanks for your inputs, I have tried this option of calling the script without 'eval' and without quotes, but I am getting an error at the line while calling `$servicestartcommand`. error is `No such file or directorysh: line 7: /home/gannu_lee/./checker.sh`. for testing purpose and to ensure no access related issues I updated the `names.txt` file to call same `checker.sh` script (like recursive). but if I just hard code and replace `$servicestartcommand` with `/home/gannu_lee/./checker.sh` it works fine and goes to infinite loop as expected.

Comment: @anubhava Got my mistake.. replaced `/home/gannu_lee/./checker.sh` with full path `/home/gannu_lee/checker.sh` now all okay. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is much simpler than you expect.  Instead of:

```
   eval "$servicestartcommand"
```

`eval` should only be used in extreme circumstances.  All you need is

```
 $servicestartcommand
```

Note: no quotes.

As an example, try this on the command-line:

```
cmd='ls -l'
$cmd
```

That should work.  But:

```
"$cmd"
```

will fail.  It will look for a program with a space in its name called `'ls -l'`.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

May be I don't get the idea, but why not use system variables?

```
export FOO=bar
echo $FOO
```

bar